# What expression could I use for the meaning "I understand" in biz e-mail?

Tags: expressions, email

What expression could I use for 
the meaning "I understand" or "I see" in business e-mail?

For example,
A seller informed me that a shipment which I request will be arrived at tomorrow.
And I would like to say "I see". What expression is appropriate in formal business e-mail.

Comment: Provide an example sentence!

Comment: I like "Roger Wilco".      http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=roger+wilco   https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_procedure

Comment: I would say "I understand".  Clarity is more important than cuteness, and you never know whether the person on the other end has a good command of English, so keep it simple.  ("I see" could be confusing in the wrong context.)

Comment: If you don't mind using a minor sentence (http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/minor%20sentence), you could just answer "Understood."

Answer (score 3):

> Thank you for letting me know.

(This acknowledges transmission and reception of the message.)